# Convert to Object and Adding property to object of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to make filter by date with this object of array

```
const mapDateRange = () => {for (let elem in catchData) {  
   let x = {startDate:catchData[elem][0],finishDate:catchData[elem][1]};
  return x;
}};
```

but its only catch one object of array

this is latest data has processing

```
const data = {
  ["01-08-2019", "08-08-2019"],
  ["08-08-2019", "15-08-2019"],
  ["15-08-2019", "22-08-2019"],
  ["22-08-2019", "29-08-2019"]
};
```

this is what i expected

```
const data = [
  {
    startDate:"01-08-2019", finisDate:"08-08-2019"
  },
  {
    startDate:"08-08-2019", finisDate:"15-08-2019"
  },
  {
    startDate:"15-08-2019", finisDate:"22-08-2019"
  },
  {
    startDate:"22-08-2019", finisDate:"29-08-2019"
  }
];
```

Comment: Your data is not valid javascript. Are those supposed to be key-value pairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few problems in the code you wrote:

1. Your `data` started as an object (`{}`), but its built as an array, so I corrected that.
2. Your function `mapDateRange` uses `catchData` but it does not exist anywhere so I made the function except an argument, which will be the `catchData`.
3. Most important: You returned `x` which is only 1 item in the array of data. So I created an empty array and pushed `x` values to the array.

```js
const data = [
  ["01-08-2019", "08-08-2019"],
  ["08-08-2019", "15-08-2019"],
  ["15-08-2019", "22-08-2019"],
  ["22-08-2019", "29-08-2019"]
];

const mapDateRange = (catchData) => {
  let new_data = [];
  for (let elem in catchData) {
    let x = {
      startDate: catchData[elem][0],
      finishDate: catchData[elem][1]
    };
    new_data.push(x);
  }
  return new_data;
};

console.log(mapDateRange(data));
```

Comment: thanks?! :D i'd done with ```data.map(item => Object.assign({},item)).map(prop => ({startDate : prop[0],finishDate : prop[1]}));```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = [
  ["01-08-2019", "08-08-2019"],
  ["08-08-2019", "15-08-2019"],
  ["15-08-2019", "22-08-2019"],
  ["22-08-2019", "29-08-2019"]
];

const mapDataRange = (data) => {
  const result = [];
  data.forEach((item) => {
    const x = { 'startDate': item[0], 'finishDate': item[1] };
    result.push(x);
  });

  return result;
}
console.log(mapDatatRange(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way you will get your desire result by using map function

```
    data = data.map((obj) => {
    return {
        startDate: obj[0],
        finishDate: obj[1]
    }
});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: You don't need to use Object.assign, with this

Answer (score 0):

try to do with `.map` and array destructuring with ES6 syntax

```
data.map(([ startDate, finishDate ]) => { startDate, finisDate })
```